# How to grab first image attached to post and display in RSS feed?

Tags: images, rss, feed, post-thumbnails

I've seen the tutorials on how to grab the first image and display it in a post, and those on grabbing the post_thumbnail and using that in the RSS feed, but does anybody know how to grab the first image attached to a post and use that in the RSS feed?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a plugin called "RSS Custom Field Images" and it worked out of the box for me.  I could even edit it to change the size of the image to something more manageable for me.

Answer (score 2):

i actually just finished working on a site that needed images in his feeds so i ended up using this:

```
function ba_post_image_feeds($content) {
    global $post,$posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

    if(!empty($first_img)){   

        $content = '<div>' . $first_img . '</div>' . $content;
    }
    return $content;
}


add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'ba_post_image_feeds');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'ba_post_image_feeds');
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.  Not sure why it didn't work for me.  I ended up using a plugin called RSS Custom Field Images and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method.

```
function add_images_to_rss($var) {
    global $post;
    if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $tid = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID);
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($tid, 'thumbnail');
        $thumb_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($tid);
        $up = wp_upload_dir();
        print '<enclosure type="'.get_post_mime_type($tid).'" length="'.filesize($up['basedir'].'/'.$thumb_meta['file']).'" url="'.$thumb[0].'" />';
    }
}
/* Technically this format is RSS2 only */
//    add_action('rss_item','add_images_to_rss');
    add_action('rss2_item','add_images_to_rss');
//    add_action('rdf_item','add_images_to_rss');
//    add_action('atom_entry','add_images_to_rss');
```