# How do I get the URL of only the first picture in a Wordpress post?

Tags: images

How do I get the URL of only the first picture in a Wordpress post? I don't want the URL of the thumbnail, but the first picture in the post loop. I only need the URL for linking purposes.

Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to grab first image attached to post and display in RSS feed?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10447/how-to-grab-first-image-attached-to-post-and-display-in-rss-feed)

Comment: Please [search the site for related questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=get+first+image+in+post) before posting. This topic has been covered extensively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children#Show_the_first_image_associated_with_the_post).

Note that [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) returns the URL of an image's full version if you want.

Comment: Thanks Raphael. But if I were to use the function within the loop, how do I make it takes only the first image in a post on a post page? Would the $attachment_id be 1 or 0?

Comment: Nvm! I used get_post_thumbnail_id() to use as the $attachment_id in the function. Worked great! Thanks Raphael.