# Fetching full size featured image to insert in RSS Feed

Tags: post-thumbnails, rss

I am trying to fetch a full size Featured Image (or first image) of the post to appear within my RSS feed. [See here](http://feeds.feedburner.com/techzoom/kzCz)

I am using the following code

```
function firstImg( $post ) {
    $matches = array();
    $output = preg_match_all( '/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches );
    if ( isset( $matches[1][0] ) ) {
        $first_img = $matches[1][0];
    }

    if ( empty( $first_img ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $first_img;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'firstImg');
```

However, this is only fetching a 200x200 thumbnail size of the image. I want to use the full size which is 600px width.

What's missing in the code?

Thanks

Comment: It fetches the first found image URL in post content, may be you are using the 200x200 images there.

Comment: If you are using the featured image feature of WordPress you should use [the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

Comment: @abhik No, the ones in the content are 600px. I suppose, this is fetching the thumbnails which are set at 200x200 but I wanted otherwise.

Comment: @kraftner Okay let me try that.

Comment: Try declaring `$post` global variable. Also, you can first check if any featured image is available to fetch, if no featured images, pull the first found image.

Comment: It has been resolved. 
The answer can be found here => 
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/118795/display-the-first-image-from-a-post-in-rss-feed